# Can I copy files to different destinations based on a value in a database using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

Is it possible to use powershell to copy files from one location to another based on a value in a database? Below is my requirement:

1. Mapping of what files belong to which person is stored in the database.
2. I need to use the value in the db and access the file system to separate out files and create folders for one folder per person and enable scheduled copying of files.

Comment: are you asking whether it's possible, or do you need specific details of how to invoke sql commands from powershell?  (it's definitely possible...)

Comment: @calavera - Thanks. Was wondering if it is possible. I can dig into details and make sense of it.

Comment: @Rynant has you on a good path with the Lee Holmes link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do that with PowerShell. You can use or write a function like [Lee Holmes' InvokeSQLCommand](http://www.leeholmes.com/blog/2007/10/19/interacting-with-sql-databases-in-powershell-invoke-sqlcommand/) to query a database. You can fill a variable with the results and copy files based the values in the result. 
If you have specific questions on how to do this please post them as separate questions.